# Does any know if there is MongoDB-CSharp driver documentation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm looking at using the MongoDB-CSharp driver for MongoDB on a small test project.  The downloads have binary and source, but I can't find any documentation anywhere.

Does anyone know if there's documentation for MongoDB-CSharp, or should I just be reading the source??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking at the source :-). I found the Linq Integration Tests in the typedcollections branch to be a good start:

http://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp/blob/typedcollections/source/MongoDB.Tests/IntegrationTests/Linq/MongoQueryTests.cs

Craig's wiki is good too, but I only found that last weekend.

You may want to give the typedcollections branch a look rather than the downloads because that's were all the recent development has been going on.

Comment: we'll be merging my wiki into Sam's at release time.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB-CSharp is about to release a beta.  With it comes some wiki documentation.  You can check out the pre-release docs at http://wiki.github.com/craiggwilson/mongodb-csharp/.  Can you tell me what other types of information would be useful?

Comment: MongoDB-CSharp is a really nice driver.  The wiki looks great.  It looks like it's covering concepts, which are otherwise hard to see while looking at the individual APIs.  IntelliSense and good function naming makes APIs pretty self documenting. 
  What I had been looking for was info on what the content of a connection string was.  Is there a way for me to update the wiki?

Comment: Yes, there will be.  I'll make sure that is included as a part of our documentation efforts.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @UpTheCreek: this driver is deprecated.  You should use the official mongodb c# driver from 10gen.  You can get it through nuget at http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/mongocsharpdriver